# How to reference to current view in IOS using react-native?

Tags: ios, react-native, cross-platform, objective-c-swift-bridge

I'm using payment SDK for the payment system in the react-native project. I'm creating bridges to open the Payment modal and sending the events back to react-native. I'm trying to reference the current view to open the payment modal on the view and after successful payment heading back to react-native code.
[Function inside my swift file to open payment modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWqAQ.png)

Comment: Please include the code in the question and not as a picture. It would be easier that way to answer the question.